# Is it cost effective to reseed my own lawn?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

My lawn is in rough shape. I live in Colorado and I have no shade so over the years the sun has killed off the sod I planted. This fall I plan on reseeding with drought tolerant seed. I have been looking around at some of the services being offered. One company has quoted me $175 to have the lawn aerated and seed added. They will not put down any compost. Is this something that if I do it will be much more cost effective? I live on a corner lot so they will do the front, side and back.

Comment: How big an area are you planning to reseed?

Comment: Do you definitely want it aerated, even if you do it yourself? I think quality might be in question as much as whether or not it's cost effective to do at all. What quality do you expect at minimum? You could just buy grass seed and straw, and if you factor that, time and water into it, it shouldn't be that expensive.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, had some difficulty logging back in. It's common to aerate out here because the soil has a lot of clay in it so that is supposed to help loosen the soil up and allow roots to grow easier from what I have been reading.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the area being covered, you could reach a break point where the cost of renting the aerator ($50-75) and buying the seed ($25) would be somewhat less expensive than $175. But IMHO if you factor in your time to go pick up the machine, buy the seed , figure out how to use the machine effectively, do the work, and then return the machine - you are much better off paying the $175. For that money you buy back your Saturday and, at least in theory, get a professional application.

I would like to see compost go down, so you might want to find someone who will do that as well. Just be aware that the composting might cost more than the aerating and seeding.

Comment: Good points and good point on the compost. I was thinking that if I went this route I may end up doing the composting myself and throw down some additional seed so I know the yard has been seeded correctly.

Answer (score 3):

How big is the area? I would say as a refunded resource, (cheap method) buy your seed needed. Get a two handed tiller, "if abled to work" till up your dried out yard. Then dig down into your yard flipping over all the moister dirt underneath. Lay all your seed in the ground.

But just before you do all this. Depending on the area, get a cheap 9 dollar sprittser. One that is vertical of course, being the cheapest one.  Every morning right before the sun hits down on your lawn. Turn on the sprayer and let it saturate your tilled yard. After that, turn it off. Then when the sun is starting to go down, lets say 8 o clock . Turn it back on and saturate the yard. Do this everyday. Every morning and afternoon untill grass starts sprouting up. When you start having grass appear. Cease early morning waterings and only do it at sundown.

Sounds like alot of work, I know..But the cheap method is always the hard method..Me though,  I find it fun.

Comment: I have a medium sized lawn. I've be contemplating just buying sod and doing the lawn myself. We live on a corner lot and so i also need to do the side of the house. Almost a block long. I actually did this when we moved in and it was a lot of work so trying to not do that again unless all else fails. I was watching some vids on Youtube and This Old House guys were using a machine that tears into the lawn and adds seed at the same time so the seed gets embedded Was thinking that may be a good solution.

Comment: A similar method,  easier but what does the machine cost? That could be a concern,  youd still have to manage hydration aswell or it will just dry again. Of course not when the suns out or it will definately burn your yard up.

Comment: True I don't mind watering the grass. I have an irrigation system that runs more than it should. The problem is the grass I planted last time was prob not the best choice for direct sunlight. This time around I'll get something that is more drought tolerant.